# Extract coordinates of corner cells of a shapefile in Python script (QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I have a grid in a Lambert Conformal Conic projection (with columns: ID, value) and I want to extract the corners of each cell in the native projection of the grid with QGIS. In particular, I want the coordinates of each cell of the following corners:

```
x1,y1 = lower left corners
x2,y2 = upper left corners
x3,y3 = upper right corners
```

So, I need to create a txt file containing the following columns

```
ID, x1, x2, y1, y2, x3, y3, value
```

where x1,x2 etc are the coordinates in meters.

Comment: Could you post your script as it is now and say where you are stuck? And any other information that you have found while researching this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a new user in QGIS and I do not know at all how I could that. I use another gis software where I can extract the coordinates of the cell centres (even in lat/lon or native projection) and the left corner cells (only in lat/lon). So, I thought that there may be a simple solution in QGIS where I could extract all the corner cells in the native projection of the grid (and not in lon/lat coordinates)

Comment: I see more the problem to define what is upper, lower and left, right especially when rhombus ◊ . Maybe it would help to know where you need the output for...

Comment: Well, If "size"  is the horizontal resolution of the grid (e.g.1000m) then I need to extract mainly the following coordinates in meters: lower left x= xcenter -size/2, lower right x= xcenter + size/2, lower left y= ycenter-size/2, upper left y=ycenter + size/2. I hope this helped.